# How to install the django site (tar.gz) downloaded from internet

Tags: python, django

I have downloaded  this project http://code.google.com/p/django-budget/

How can i install it. Do i need to execute some commands or just extract it to some folder.

DO i need to use syncdb.

I am newbie so don't know much

Comment: Do you know enough to read a file called "README.rst"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS. It's been moved to https://github.com/toastdriven/django-budget for a while now.

There is information on the frontpage of the site:

> **Installation**
>
> - Either copy/symlink the budget app
>     into your project or place it
>     somewhere on your PYTHONPATH.
> - Add the budget.categories,
>     budget.transactions and budget apps to
>     your INSTALLED_APPS.
> - Run ./manage.py syncdb.
> - Add (r'^budget/',
>     include('budgetproject.budget.urls')),
>     to your urls.py.

You need Python and Djano installed.

Comment: I read that but could not fully understood that. Do i still need to excute startproject command and then copy the files. Which database it will go by default

Comment: @user786783 Copy the app into your current project or to Python path (probably set as an environment variable). Then add the 3 apps to your Django installed apps. Run "manage.py syncdb". Add "(r'^budget/', include('budgetproject.budget.urls'))" to urls.py. Pretty simple to me, coming from someone who's never touched the framework before.

Comment: you said `current project`. so it means i need not to create any new project for that. i was thinking it as full fledge project. so if i have one site already called site1 then i should copy it there

Comment: @user786783 , **or place it somewhere in your Python path**